# Is there a way to delete a project on readthedocs.org?

Tags: read-the-docs

I'm getting started with readthedocs.{org,io} and created a project in error that I'd now like to delete. I've looked at the various things I can do to a project and am not seeing any buttons labeled "Delete" and I'm not finding any documentation about deleting incorrect projects in the support pages.

Is this just a feature that hasn't been implemented yet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are still in need of an answer: Under [cog]Admin button, scroll all the way to the bottom and next to Save is a Delete Project option.

Comment: correction, click on account, then project, then Admin/gear, then next to save it's delete